# Entity Framework Code Most First Efficient Linq Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following entities (reduced for brevity);

```
public class Job {
   Hospital Hospital { get; set; }
   Status Status { get; set; }
}

public class User {
   string UserId { get; set; }
   string UserName { get; set; } 
}

public class UserHospital {
   User User { get; set;}
   Hospital Hospital { get; set; }
}

public class Hospital {
   int HospitalId { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to get a List of all jobs in a particular status where a user has a UserHospital relationship to the Job.

With the way the POCOs are laid out I would assume I would have to get all the UserHospital relationships and then build

```
var userHospitals = context.Where<UserHospital>(x => x.User.UserName == "username").ToList();
```

and then loop through and build a list from the Job perspective?

```
var jobs = new List<Job>();

foreach(var userHospital in userHospitals)
   jobs.AddRange(context.Where<Job>(x => x.Hospital.Id == userHospital.Hospital.Id).ToList())

return jobs;
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: so, User should have reference to set of Hospitals, Hospital - to set of Users

Comment: Correct and then a job has a reference to a hospital.

Comment: It might be just me, but this database structure seems a little odd. If you want to connect users to jobs, why would you have this go through a hospital? I think you might want to rethink your database structure

Comment: I think you may want to use a JOIN.  See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: If you don't have more information on the `UserHospital` object, then you should just define it as a many-to-many relationship (collection on both `User` and `Hospital`), and let the cross reference class exist only as a table in the database with no code representation.

Comment: @Bas The Job does have a Link to User (left out for brevity) however at the current point in time this null. Essentially, Jobs are raised for a particular hospital and users will attend to these jobs, as the userhospitals over lap their is amany to many relationship, i cant see how to improve upon this structure?

Comment: @MatthewFlynn sorry, you didn't show the relation from Job-User.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var res=context.Where<Job>(j=> context.Any<UserHospital>(u=>u.User.Username=="username" && u.Hospital.Id==j.Hospital.Id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a separate entity for User <-> Hospital many to many relationship?
If you had a collection on each side like this.

```
Hospital {
   Icollection<User> Users{get;set;}
}
```

your Query would be as simple as
`context.Jobs.Where(j=>j.Hospital.Users.Any(u=>u.username=="something"))` and that would translate good.